# Mouse events not firing on control when form is transparent

Tags: c#, transparent

I set my forms back color to Black. I set the transparency key to Black as well. My controls have the back color of Transparent because I want to see the image behind it but this prevents my controls from having mouse events. I want to be able to click on my panels still.

Attached is a picture that shows the panels but clicking them doesn't do anything. Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Could you possibly include some of the code you have used to do this? It's much easier to help you when we can see some code...

Comment: I'm not really sure what code I can show that will help. I set the forms back color and transparency color in the designer to Black. Then the panel's back color is set to transparent. And doing this prevents the click event from firing on the panel. If I set the panel's back color to something else other than black or transparent the click event works.

Comment: Are you using Transparent control in C# ?

Comment: Transparent control? Yes?

Comment: Catch the mouse events in the form and translate them to the control by location?

Comment: use `Red` as `BackColor` and `TransparencyKey` of `Form`.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work, I tried it

Comment: The behavior is different for different colors. Use `Red`. Also take a look at linked post.

Comment: I tried a bunch of different colors, that doesn't seem to make the click event fire still

Comment: Did you try exactly `Red` for `BackColor` and `TransparencyKey` of `Form`. At the moment I have a form and a label on it, the label `BackColor` is `Transparent` and I can click on it and Show a MessageBox.

Comment: Really? Because yes my form back color is red and so is transparency key. My panel's back color is transparent. And clicking doesnt do anything

Comment: I saw someone suggest this in another post but its not working for me... weird

Comment: It seems that clicking on the text on a label will trigger the event but the transparent back color wont. Gah